# Securing asp.net web services to be consumed from flash

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, actionscript

my team is building a game in flash to be embeded in a asp.net application.

When the game is over the player have the chance to type his name to save his score.
This is done using web services called from flash. The webservice receives the name and score.

Since the webservice is publicly available how can I make it only callable from my flash given the following conditions:

- The .swf is hosted by the same asp.net application
- There are two domains that can access the same application (I have run previously into cross domain issues).
- Using SSL is not an option.
- The webservice has to be consumed by the .swf file.

Any help or code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well If you want to use ASP.NET webapplication instead of webservice , I have a solution which worked on my Project.

You can send variables from flash to you ASP.NET page using  `LoadVars' and 'sendAndLoad`. then can get the values in .NET webpage using `Request.Form`. Now as you have all the variables from Flash to your .NET webpage , do what ever processing you need(Ado.NET or Sending a mail to user)

Here is a [sample](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=252746) to get you started with though it is in ASP , can be easily used in ASP.NET.

But if your are trying to use webService connector in Flash m not sure about it and do not see why to use webservice while we can use webapp?

Crossdomain.xml (policy file) is really important here.

**Edit**
To send the data from flash to webservice we can use some approach as below.

```
var wsConn:WebServiceConnector = new WebServiceConnector();
wsConn.addEventListener("status",fault);
wsConn.addEventListener("result",res);
wsConn.multipleSimultaneousAllowed = true;
//The following WSDL has been deployed locally. Most cases you will have another URL
wsConn.WSDLURL = "http://localhost/flightstatus/FlightHistoryService.wsdl";
//Method you need to call
wsConn.operation = "FlightHistoryGetHistoryOperation";
//Will Send the params as an array to the Webservice
wsConn.params = [flightHistoryRequest];
//wsConn.suppressInvalidCalls = true;
  wsConn.trigger();
```

For complete reference please refer to article on my [Blog](http://blog.subhendu.info/index.php/connecting-to-webservice-using-adobe-flash-action-script-2-0-as2-with-complex-datatype/).

Comment: The whole game is in flash and to save the score in the DB a web service in my as.net app has to be called. Or is there any other way to securely send data to my asp.net app?

Comment: @Carlos Muñoz, You don't need a webservice. Just in your .CS file(if you write with C#) load the Flash Variables and then save them to database

Comment: Sending parameters via POST to a webpage isn't remotely secure. The webservice suffers from the same weakness though.

Comment: Agree and SSL is not an option. If you write encode and decode then it will add performance overhead .

Comment: Performance overhead is meaningless here, the important issue is to send data from flash to c# webservice and to make sure only flash can call it.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz, Updated my answer with WebServiceconnector code. Though this is long time you wanted the answer still I am updating as it may help someone else :) But Still I am not sure how you will secure your data as it still may be seen by some one who is sitting between client and server, not matter if you use webservice or webapp in this case